# How and when does a text file or json file get closed?

Tags: python, json, file, text-files

I was having some errors when accessing the dict opened via json and while reading around here discovered that the dict I was trying to access (from a text file) was closed. How does the file get closed in this simplified version of what I am doing?

**Code:**

```
import json

with open('nID.txt') as json_file:
    data = json.load(json_file)
    print(data)
    print('R1N1x       :', data['R1N1']['x'])
    print('R1N1y       :',  data['R1N1']['y'])
    print('R1N500x     :', data['R1N500']['x'])
    print('R1N500y     :', data['R1N500']['y'])
    print('R2N1x       :', data['R2N1']['x'])
    print('R2N1y       :',  data['R2N1']['y'])
    print('R2N500x     :', data['R2N500']['x'])
    print('R2N500y     :', data['R2N500']['y'])





if json_file.closed:
  print('file is closed')
```

Comment: With the “with” statement - https://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm , https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html , https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html

Comment: @user2864740 Does that mean that it is opened - stored in memory as json_file and then closed again?

Comment: Not because of the “with”; that is the result js json.load, where the opened file resource is used. See the links (just added). The “with” controls the lifetime of the file resource itself. However, the JSON has been loaded into memory data structures _independently_ of the file resource.

Comment: since you opened the file in a "with" statement, after all the commands inside its block have been run, the file closes automatically, removing it from memory

Comment: Can either of you post that as an answer, I will accept it. Thank you

Comment: Note: if you're interested, you can read about *context managers* (https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers). I think, it's an important concept to know in Python.

Comment: @Green thank you, book marked it for this afternoon

Comment: @user2864740 can you post your comments as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The with statement automatically closes the variable or file in this case at the end of the suite,

if you don't want that to be the case remove the with statement and end with json_file.close()

The with statement was added in 3.4 I believe

Here's the docs :

https://docs.python.org/2.5/whatsnew/pep-343.html

For all statements:

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html